# Assigning shortcuts to AltGr when it is set as ISO_Level3_Shift

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, xkb, remapping

I am using a custom keyboard layout. I duplicated the "intl" from /usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/us within the same file, called it "myintl" and altered the 3rd and 4th level of some keys to produce the characters of my desire. This layout has an "include "level3(ralt_switch)" in it, which means AltGr acts as "ISO_Level3_Shift". And that all works fine.

However, I would like to assign shortcuts to AltGr + some other keys for launching programs or similar.

For example:
"AltGr + ." (period) should run/switch to Double Commander.
I have actually achieved this using xbindkeys, but it warns me that there seems to be a conflict and it can't grab all the defined keys.

Another example:
"AltGr + NumPad0" should type the current date/time stamp to whichever window is focused.
I added the following to $HOME/.xbindkeysrc

```
"xdotool type --clearmodifiers $(date +%Y%m%d)"
  m:0x90 + c:90 + release
```

but it is typing partly the level3 characters depending on how early I release the AltGr key
xdotool is also doing this on its own in the terminal. Maybe it it this bug https://github.com/jordansissel/xdotool/issues/97.
It's the same with `xte`

I'd prefer to use the Gnome Settings > Keyboard Shortcuts for assigning shortcuts, but obviously it only detects the final character as specified in the layout file and then just types that instead of doing the desired action.

Either way, having AltGr act as the level3 Shift seems to be interfering with shortcut-making tools.

So how can I have AltGr type the level 3 and 4 characters together with the some keys and to act as a shortcut component together with some other keys?

Similar, but does not quite answer my question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48464770/set-up-a-shortcut-keybinding-under-gnu-linux-with-altgr-key-but-autokey-nor-o